# × React -TypeError: _this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi i have a react function

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import StaticPage from '../../components/StaticPage';
import faq from './faq.md';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-styled-flexboxgrid';
import GlobalStyles from '../../components/GlobalStyles';
import Link from '../../components/Link'
//Material-ui
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/FontIcon';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
//css
import styled from 'styled-components';
// Third party imports
 import _ from 'lodash'


function action() {
  let value = 'null'

  let DATA = [{
    question: 'Lorem12',
    answer: ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.']
  }, {
    question: 'Lorem',
    answer: [`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`]
    }, {
      question: 'Lorem2',
      answer: [`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`]
    }]

  let onFilterData = (e) => {
    if (this.filterFn) {
      clearTimeout(this.filterFn)
    }
  let searchText = this.searchText
    this.filterFn = setTimeout( () => this.setState({searchText: value}), 350 )
  }

  return {
    chunks: ['faq'], // routes

    component: (
      <Layout>
        {/* From Import faq */}
        <div style={{backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', padding: '32px 24px'}}>
          <Grid>
            <GlobalStyles />
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12}  style={{backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <h2>FAQs |  We’re here to help!</h2>
                <p className='text lightBlack'>Got other questions? Lorem</p>
                <Col xs={12} smOffset={4} sm={6} md={4} style={{marginBottom: 10, textAlign: 'center'}}>
                  <Paper style={{backgroundColor: '#1875D1', display: 'table'}}>
                    <TextField
                      hintText='What can we help you with?'
                      underlineStyle={{display: 'none'}}
                      fullWidth
                      style={{display: 'table-cell', backgroundColor: '#ffffff', paddingLeft: 15, verticalAlign: 'middle'}}
                      onChange={onFilterData.bind(this.searchText)}
                      />
                    <IconButton style={{display: 'table-cell', verticalAlign: 'middle', color: '#ffffff'}}>
                      <FontIcon
                        style={{backgroundColor: '#1875D1', padding: 5}}
                        color={'#fffff'}
                        className='material-icons'>search</FontIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                  </Paper>
                </Col>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12} md={3}>
              <div style={{position: '-webkit-sticky', position: 'sticky', top: 0, padding: 12}}>
              <h4 style={{paddingTop: 8}}><strong>Browse by topic</strong></h4>

              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12} md={9}>
              {_.map(_.filter(DATA, d => _.indexOf(_.toLower(d.question), _.toLower(this.searchText)) > -1 || _.indexOf(_.toLower(d.answer), _.toLower(this.searchText)) > -1), d =>
                <div style={{borderBottom: 'solid 1px black', marginBottom: 28}}>
                  {_.map(d.answer, a => <p>{a}</p>)}
                </div>
              )}
              <div id='orders'>
                <div style={{borderBottom: 'solid 1px black'}}>
                  <h3>Lorem12</h3>
                  <p style={{marginBottom: 28}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div style={{borderBottom: 'solid 1px black'}}>
                  <h3>Lorem</h3>
                  <p style={{marginBottom: 28}}>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div style={{borderBottom: 'solid 1px black'}} >
                  <h3>Lorem2</h3>
                  <p style={{marginBottom: 28}}>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </Layout>
    ),
  };
}

export default action;
```

Im creating '** onFilterData'** for filtering the words, my **DATA** is contains the filtering of the words

I have an error inside in my function

> this.filterFn = setTimeout( () => this.setState({searchText: value}),
>   350 )

The error I get  **TypeError: _this.setState is not a function**

I hope someone could help me with my error

Comment: Can you clean your code to keep only the relevant parts? Can't find anything in there...

Comment: you want to set state on functional (stateless component) ?

Comment: @ivica.moke Yes i want to setState I dont want to create a state.

Comment: @ChrisR Done Cleaning some code, sorry for making it messy

Comment: This is stateless component. You want to use setState, you must change it to class and extends React.Component

Comment: i think you cannot use this.setState within a function which is stateless. You need a class that extends React.Component and inside that you can do this.setState

Comment: I there anyway ? to change the value without using state ?

Comment: Many, but a component state is the most reliable and convenient.

Comment: I cant use the state component in my project due of config in our projects :/ that's why Im searching how to do it without using state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your component from stateLess to stateFul then use `setState`.

Using `React.Component`:

```
class Action extends React.Component {}
```

Instead of using function:

```
function action() {}
```

Some Stuff for deeper understanding:

[Read more about stateFul components](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

[Read more about the difference between stateFul and stateLess components](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stateful-vs-stateless-functional-components-in-react--cms-29541)

Comment: Thanks Mate! for the article, but am trying not to use stateless instead using lodash assign

Comment: @MikeVictoria your welcome. you can also use 'recompose' https://github.com/acdlite/recompose